# Vlookup inside multiple ifs and and's formula error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables that contains multiple values and need to get exact value from the second table to the first on e

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,$I$9:$R$18,IF(D3=23800,10,IF(D3>10000,9,IF(AND(7000<D3,D3<10000),8,IF(AND(5000<D3,D3<7000),7,IF(AND(3000<D3,D3<5000),6,IF(AND(1000<D3,D3<3000,5,IF(AND(500<D3,D3<1000,4,IF(D3<500,3,2)))))))))
```

this is my code and i get an error each time i try to correct this. How can i solve my problem on the code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error and kindly share some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you break up the formula like below, you'll notice that you are missing two closing parens:

```
=VLOOKUP(
  A3,
  $I$9:$R$18,
  IF(
    D3=23800,
    10,
    IF(
      D3>10000,
      9,
      IF(
        AND(7000<D3,D3<10000),
        8,
        IF(
          AND(5000<D3,D3<7000),
          7,
          IF(
            AND(3000<D3,D3<5000),
            6,
            IF(
              AND(1000<D3,D3<3000,        <= here
              5,
              IF(
                AND(500<D3,D3<1000,       <= here
                4,
                IF(
                  D3<500,
                  3,
                  2
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I would suggest that instead of having all those nested `IF`s to have a lookup table, it might also help making the logic clearer. For instance, the last `IF` has: if D3 is less than 500, then it should return 3, else 2. If D3 is not less than 500, it surely means that it is larger than 500, which would actually be falling in the condition that was checked earlier, when you had `AND(500<D3,D3<1000)`, so...

```
=VLOOKUP(D3,$G$3:$H$10,2,1)
```

[image]

In that case, your formula might look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,$I$9:$R$18,VLOOKUP(D3,$G$3:$H$10,2,1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made it much easier for me